# Nested guest VM on ESXI is not able to access internet but can access host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, bridge, qemu, esxi

I am running x86 Ubuntu 20 on ESXI 7.0 (lets call this as my host VM). On top of Ubuntu VM, I am launching ARM64 RaspiOS using QEMU (this is my guest VM). So you can say I have nested VMs.

From my host machine (which is given static IP 10.105.226.235), I am able to access internet and can ping the outer world DNS servers and a physical test machine which has IP 10.105.226.233. Following are my host interfaces. You can see I have setup a bridge `br0` and a `tap0` tap interface.

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.105.226.235  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.105.255.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe4b:7671  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:4b:76:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1903892  bytes 1396076191 (1.3 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 9002  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 646750  bytes 62291464 (62.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens160: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0c:29:4b:76:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8095571  bytes 10049111257 (10.0 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3854356  bytes 269349233 (269.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 59808  bytes 4751233 (4.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 59808  bytes 4751233 (4.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tap0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::249d:9cff:fe6e:55d8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 26:9d:9c:6e:55:d8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12437  bytes 1336737 (1.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 74581  bytes 16655854 (16.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 1 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

From my ARM64 guest qemu VM, I am able to ping the host but not able to ping the DNS servers or the test machine with IP 10.105.226.233. I have enabled promiscous mode in ESXI if that matters. Following are how my interfaces look like in qemu VM.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.105.226.232  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.105.226.255
        ether 52:55:00:d1:55:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 120  bytes 8973 (8.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 50  bytes 5226 (5.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 25  bytes 2119 (2.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25  bytes 2119 (2.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pi@raspberrypi:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.105.226.232
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 10.105.226.1
  dns-nameservers 68.152.128.40
  dns-nameservers 67.154.138.36
```

Can someone please help how can I reach the internet  and my test machine, from the guest QEMU VM.

Answer (score -1):

It is an expected behavior for ESXi-based nested virtualization. You need to configure promiscuous mode on vSwitch, which is used by Ubuntu for nested network. https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1002934

How to configure promiscuous mode  on switch is described here - https://www.vmwareblog.org/build-home-lab-using-pc-part-1-2-setting-vmware-vsan-nested-esxi-hosts/

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I have mentioned that I have enabled it already.